# Merriam-Webster definition of "Sheeps"

Tags: meaning

Sheep is a noun, and the plural of sheep is "sheep".

However I recently came across the Merriam-Webster definition of [SHEEPS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sheeps) which states it is "present tense third person singular of SHEEP"
"Present tense" would lead me to think "SHEEP" would be a verb, but I have not heard it used that way and the definitions of "[SHEEP](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sheep)" within M-W that the page links to are all nouns.

A little Googling shows me cases of "Sheeps" which are possessive but missing or misplacing the apostrophe, or occasionally used as a plural (in cases that seem just to be mistakes on the part of a non-English speaker/writer) but no case I can see where it is a verb.

Is M-W just wrong in this entry, or is there a source or explanation for this?

Comment: It seems odd that they say *sheeps* is a form of a verb, but link to a noun only (*sheep*)

Comment: Their website says: "you are looking for [a word] that’s only in the Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary." Apparently you need the paid version to see the verb.

Comment: @alphabet none of the dictionaries I have access to at home or online have a verb definition, so it's rather odd that they claim one

Comment: Related: ***Can Sheep be a verb?*** https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61436/can-sheep-be-a-verb

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OED has *sheep* as a verb. It's marked "local" and hasn't been revised since the last quotation was included in 1922:

> 1. *transitive.* To weed or to dung (land) by pasturing sheep upon it.
>
>    > **1898**
>    > The best chance of turning it into a really sound pasture is to **sheep** it heavily.
>    > H. R. Haggard, *Farmer's Year* (1899) 101
> 2. To eat *off* with sheep.
>
>    > **1922**
>    > But what if you throwed your sheep round my range an' **sheeped off** the grass so my cattle would hev to move or starve?
>    > Z. Grey, *To Last Man* iv

---

*Eat off* is now unusual, too. This entry hasn't been revised since 1891:

> 2. To clear off (a crop) by feeding it to cattle: said also of the cattle. Also *intransitive* (for *passive*) of a crop.

Comment: So I (or Google) didn't find "sheeps" either by not going far enough back, or just because only other versions of the verb were used.

Comment: Possibly. If you're using ngrams then it's also possible that Google misidentified the verb as a noun. It's really uncommon, so it's not altogether surprising that even Google results show very few examples (that is, you need to trawl through loads of pages to find one). I didn't use Google.